# Oops; flutter has exited unexpectedly: "Error on line 8, column 2: Expected ':'

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code, localization

I was attempting to internationalize my app and went through the Flutter official docs and everything went fine yesterday. Today when I ran the application on the simulator again the following error was outputted:

[image: Error output]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:flutter_localizations/flutter_localizations.dart';
import 'package:flutter_gen/gen_l10n/app_localizations.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';
import 'package:services_app/providers/language_provider.dart';
import 'package:services_app/util/const.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Services App',
      theme: ThemeData(
        fontFamily: Constants.ENFONTFAMILY,
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      localizationsDelegates: const [
        AppLocalizations.delegate,
        GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
        GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
        GlobalCupertinoLocalizations.delegate,
      ],
      supportedLocales: const [Locale('en', ''), Locale('ar', '')],
      home: Home(),
    );
  }
}

// ignore: use_key_in_widget_constructors
class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle.dark.copyWith(
      statusBarBrightness: Brightness.light,
      statusBarIconBrightness: Brightness.light,
    ));
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: InkWell(
          onTap: () {},
          child: Text(AppLocalizations.of(context)!.helloWorld,
              style: const TextStyle(
                fontSize: 24,
              )),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image: Flutter doctor output]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

If it says "Access denied" it might be because you installed it with admin privilege's. Try deleting your current install of Flutter and re-installing it following the official guide from the doc i.e; `flutter.dev` and check if the folder has correct permissions